# Passing variables for gritter gem to translate in gflash.en.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, i18n-gem, gritter

How do you pass a variable or argument to the [gritter Ruby on Rails gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gritter) so that it can be used as part of internationalisation (i18n) replacement?

You can hard code gflash in the controller like so:

```
butter = 'melted'
gflash :notice => "The knob of butter is #{butter}"
```

In the above, `#{butter}` is replaced with "melted".

But that leaves the translation set in the controller, ignoring the use of the gflash.en.yml file, and at one language.

Testing with variants on how to call the variable seems to result in no substitution.

```
en:
  gflash:
    titles:
      notice: "Notice"
    accounts:
      login:
        notice: "@butter     {butter}    $butter      #butter     %butter       
                 %{@butter}  %{#@butter} %#{@butter}  %#{butter}  %s
                 %@butter    %{#butter}  #{@butter}   #@butter    {#@butter}   
                 %{butter}   #{butter}   ${butter}    @{butter}"
```

Not one of the above keys in the gflash.en.yml file display "melted" and instead just show as-is.

Trying to pass it like so also will not work:

```
gflash :notice => {:butter => 'melted'}
```

Is there a way to pass variables to the translation keys for the gritter gem to use instead of being limited to hard code one language in the controller?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that it allows any variables: https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter/blob/master/lib/gritter/gflash.rb#L48

I guess you can do something like this then:

```
gflash :notice => t("gflash.#{params[:controller]}.#{params[:action]}.notice", butter: butter)
```

But the best way would be to create an GH issue (with pull request preferably).

Comment: That works, but may cause issues from the directory slash (say in "admin/recipes") where it looks for en.gflash.admin/recipes.edit.notice, so just direct reference fixes it as well, like `gflash :notice => t("gflash.admin.recipes.edit.notice")`

Comment: Fair point, you can create a helper method to make that dynamic.